# .map is not a function [React & Firestore]

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been fighting this error in my code,  I am creating a dropdown menu that maps the collections in my Firestore database. It is rendering the courses however, when I click on one, it gives me the following error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import './add.css'

export default class add extends Component {

    state = {
        course: 'TestCourse1',
        question: '',
        questionType: 'MultipleChoice',
        correctAnswer: '',
        wrongAnswer: '',
        wrongAnswer2: '',
        wrongAnswer3: '',
        courses: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let db = firebase.firestore()

        db.collection('courses').get().then(snapshot => {
            const courses = []
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                const data = doc.data()
                courses.push(data)
            })
            this.setState({courses})
        }).catch(error => { console.error(error) })
    }


    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
        }) 
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state)
    }



    render() {

        const {courses} = this.state
        return (
            <div className = "Container">
            <div className = "AddQuestion">
               <h1> Add a question </h1>
               <div className = "AddQuestionFormContainer">
                <form>

                    <label htmlFor = "courses"> Courses</label>  <br/>
                    <select name = "course" id = "courses" onChange = {this.handleChange} value = {this.state.course}>
                    {
                        courses && courses.map(course => {
                            return <option value = {course.courseName} key = {course.courseName}> {course.courseName}</option>
                        })

                    }
                    </select> <br/><br/>

                    <label  htmlFor = "question"> Question </label>  <br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "question" placeholder = "Enter your question" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <br/><br/>

                    <label  htmlFor = "question"> Question Type </label><br/>
                    <select name = "questionType" id = "questionType" onChange={this.handleChange} value = {this.state.questionType}  >
                        <option value = "MultipleChoice" > Multiple Choice</option>
                        <option value = "TrueOrFalse"> True or False </option>
                    </select>
                    <br/><br/>

                    <label  htmlFor = "correctAnswer"> Correct Answer</label> <br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "correctAnswer" placeholder = "Correct Answer" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <label  htmlFor = "wrongAnswer"> Wrong Answers </label><br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "wrongAnswer" placeholder = "Wrong Answer" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "wrongAnswer2" placeholder = "Wrong Answer" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "wrongAnswer3" placeholder = "Wrong Answer" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br/> <br/> 

                    <button onClick = {this.handleSubmit}> Submit </button>





                </form>
               </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The value of the object is rendering to my state fine, it's just when I go to select an option in my dropdown it returns the error!

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

After adding a console.log in my componentDidMount(), this is what is returned

CODE

```
 componentDidMount() {
        let db = firebase.firestore()

        db.collection('courses').get().then(snapshot => {
            const courses = []
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                const data = doc.data()
                courses.push(data)
                console.log(courses)
            })
            this.setState({courses})
        }).catch(error => { console.error(error) })
    }
```

Console.log

[image]

Comment: check the `courses` array after the `forEach` loop

Comment: I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is happening because,  In the state you are defining `courses` as an array. But while `handleChange` overriding it into a string.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
       // Here overriding the value of courses to a string
        this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value //targetId is `courses` and the value is a string
        }) 
    }
```

According to my understanding, you will have to track the selected course. For that change the `id` of `select` to `course`

```
<select
        name="course"
        id="course"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        value={this.state.course}
      >
```

sample demo:- https://codesandbox.io/s/black-butterfly-2shjv?file=/src/App.js

Please let me know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: You're a life saver! It's always something silly :P worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: glad that I helped you

Answer (score 0):

First thing make sure your service returning an array to 'courses' and I recommend you to write like this

```
courses.length && courses.map(course => {
      return <option value = {course.courseName} key={course.courseName}> 
               {course.courseName}
            </option>});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the '.length' didn't solve my issue but I appreciate the input :D I am very new to stuff like this.

Comment: @RyanNisbet Are you sure your service returning an array to you . You can check it simply use console.log()

Comment: I have edited the original post adding the console.log and what it returned.